# dropna is filling all the column with None rather than just the NaN values

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, nan, in-place

Working with a DataFrame about places to start and places to go, kind of a Uber app.

It is given to me a DataFrame with 2 columns that have lots of NaN values: Some of them are NaN and other are string types that are written as "nan". An example of how it is written could be this:

```
data = [
    ["Sevilla","Granada"],
    ["nan","Madrid"],
    ["Burgos",NaN],
    ["Badajoz","Valencia"],
    [NaN,NaN],
    [NaN,"nan"],
    [NaN,"Barcelona"]
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data,
        columns=["start_station_name", "end_station_name"],
    )
    print(df)
```

So you should eliminate both the "nan" and the NaN. The main problem is that when I use .dropna(inplace=True) it eliminates all the values and appears None, how do I keep the good ones?

What I´ve tried is the following.

First, I have replaced all the "nan" with are not NaN values by NotaNumbers.
Second, I have dropped all the NaN values, while keeping the name of the cities.

```
    df["start_station_name"] = df["start_station_name"].replace("nan",np.nan)
    df["end_station_name"] = df["end_station_name"].replace("nan",np.nan)

    df["start_station_name"] = df["start_station_name"].dropna(inplace=True)
    df["end_station_name"] = df["end_station_name"].dropna(inplace=True)

    print(df[["start_station_name","end_station_name"]])
```

It shows only None (So all the values are None)

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output to ensure there is no ambiguity?

Comment: Yes, what I was expecting is: [[
    ["Sevilla","Granada"],
    ["Badajoz","Valencia"]]
Sorry if it is not written properly, I don´t know how towrite outputs yet.

Comment: Please [edit] the question ;)

Comment: But then you want to use the default `how='any'` in `dropna`. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) directly, not at the column/Series level:

```
out = df.replace('nan', float('nan')).dropna()
```

Output:

```
  start_station_name end_station_name
0            Sevilla          Granada
3            Badajoz         Valencia
```

Your original approach didn't work because you were dropping the NaNs for each column individually, but the columns are reindexed upon insertion back into the DataFrame, which recreates the NaNs.

##### note in the original answer

(not needed but just left here in case it's useful to others)

If for some reason you want to keep the existing string `'nan'`, but still use them to drop the rows in which all values are NaN/'nan':

```
out = df[df.replace('nan', float('nan')).notna().any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
  start_station_name end_station_name
0            Sevilla          Granada
1                nan           Madrid  # notice the 'nan'
2             Burgos              NaN
3            Badajoz         Valencia
6                NaN        Barcelona
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a couple of questions, when you use replace, why do you write `float("nan")` and not `np.nan`?

Comment: @ManuelVeiga it's the same. `float('nan')` doesn't require to have imported numpy.